# Elastic CSS for iPhone

Tags: iphone, css

the vertical iPhone viewport width is 320 px, but what is the width in ems

or

what is the default font size in px in the iphone

Comment: Width in `em`s depends on text size.

Comment: yes, but the default size in the pc browsers (firefox, safari, ie, etc) is 16px (=1em). What is the default size in the iphone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test with the viewport set to the iphone width:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

and...

```
<span style="font-size:16px">A</span>
```

is the same size as

```
<span style="font-size:1em">A</span>
```

both in the vertical and horizontal orientation

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?
http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/07/web-development-for-the-iphone/

But maybe you can use a variation of this:
http://www.everythingicafe.com/forum/iphone-software/increase-font-size-in-safari-without-zooming-9511.html

to set a font size that stays the same, which would answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

320px = 20ems. I think the default size is 12px; it's set to "Medium", which in most cases is 12px.

Comment: An em is based off the point size of the font. 320px will be 20ems only if the font is a 16 point font.